# Change from quirks mode IE 5.5 to just quirks mode

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype, quirks-mode

After a lot of time spent trying to solve this issue, I'm here to ask your help.

My website does not have a doctype and is working fine with all browsers, including IE.

I know it is not correct but any DOCTYPE I put breaks the code in some point.

The fact is that my document mode is in quirks 5.5

At IE, I changed it to just quirks mode (second option in the menu) and all worked perfect.

So, besides the fact that it does not have a doctype, is there any way to change from quirks 5.5 to just quirks?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't stress enough just how much bad it is to stick with quirks mode. I don't know how you got it working in IE and other browsers at the same time without a doctype but I'm guessing it involves a lot of CSS hacks. My sincere advice is to rip out all those hacks and put in a doctype. You say you've spent a lot of time on this; you would probably have sorted it by now if you'd done it properly to start with. Sticking with quirks mode is going to keep on giving you problems, and as time goes by and browsers mode on that will only get worse. Do it right now and save yourself a lot of hassle.

Comment: Exactly. Different browsers have different quirks, so your website will not display the same across browsers. If it were really "working fine with all browsers" then you wouldn't really have come here for help, no? Draw your own conclusion.

Comment: I can't re-do all my website because 1) I don't have the experience and knowlodge and 2) I don't have the money to hire someone else and 3) It will took at least 3 months and I have daily costumers. Even that it is not a good practice, the best solution right now is to force a quirks mode. The only 2 possible options for the moments are 1) force quirks mode or 2) let the code broke.

Comment: Your third option, of course, is to ask for help getting it out of quirks mode. You never know, it might not take as much work as you think -- put the doctype in, add `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to your CSS, and tell us what breaks.

Comment: [Relevant info from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This page states that quirks mode is different in IE10 to earlier versions of IE. IE9 and earlier did not have two different quirks modes. It sounds like you have IE10. If you stick with quirks mode, please be aware that you will need to test in other IE versions as well, because it will be different to what you see in IE10. (you can see just what a mess quirks mode is, right?)

Comment: Quirks mode is driving me NUTS! Daaamn! I have put a doctype but only the Css hack could handle all the mess.

Comment: @Spudley it wasn't that hard to change do Standard mode. I did not changed the whole website, but 3 or 4 pages are fine now. All I did was the box-sizing css with vertical-align:bottom. Thanks a lot my friend!!!!

Comment: @gscrmn - That's good. I'll post it as an answer below so you can click the tick to accept it.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

(Posting an answer derived from my comments above, since OP indicates that it helped him solve the problem)

You should **not** use Quirks mode. There are too many issues around it to make it a sensible option under any circumstances.

And it really isn't that difficult to convert away from Quirks mode.

1. Add a `DOCTYPE` (you already know about this).

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   This will tell the browser to use standards mode.
2. Add the following line to your CSS:

   ```
   * {box-sizing:border-box;}
   ```

   This is the standards-compliant way of emulating the main thing in quirks mode that causes layout difference, which is the different box model that quirks mode used.

There may be a few other minor tweaks you need to do, but `box-sizing` should deal with the vast majority of the layout changes you get when you move away from quirks mode.

Hope that helps.